# What's the technical term for a REST API that can accept/send multiple content types for the same endpoint?

Tags: polymorphism, definition

Is there a technical term to describe the concept of an endpoint being able to accept/respond with multiple types depending on the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers supplied by the client?

For example, a `GET` `/api/users/:id` endpoint can reply with either `json` or `protobuf` depending on the Client's `Accept` header.

Also the `PUT` `/api/users` endpoint can accept either `json` or `protobuf` depending on the `Content-Type` header sent by the client.